# sscanf linux kernel differs from sscanf glibc

Tags: c, linux-kernel, glibc, scanf, format-string

Running the following code (`make runtest`) on my machine (`4.6.4-1-ARCH`)

```
/* scanf userland & kernelspace test */

#if __KERNEL__

#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/string.h>

MODULE_AUTHOR("Enteee (duckpond.ch) ");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("scanf test");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_ALIAS("scanf_test");

#else

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define printk printf

#endif

void test(void){
    int ret = 0;
    char fp[20] = { 0 };

    memset(fp, 0xaa, sizeof(fp));
    printk("init, ret = %d fp = "
            "%2.2hhx%2.2hhx%2.2hhx%2.2hhx%2.2hhx%2.2hhx"
            "%2.2hhx%2.2hhx%2.2hhx%2.2hhx%2.2hhx%2.2hhx"
            "%2.2hhx%2.2hhx%2.2hhx%2.2hhx%2.2hhx%2.2hhx"
            "%2.2hhx%2.2hhx, "
            // overflow prints (hacky)
            "after fp = "
            "%2.2hhx%2.2hhx%2.2hhx%2.2hhx%2.2hhx%2.2hhx, "
            "before fp = "
            "%2.2hhx%2.2hhx%2.2hhx%2.2hhx%2.2hhx%2.2hhx"
            "\n",
            ret,
            (fp)[0],  (fp)[1],  (fp)[2],  (fp)[3],  (fp)[4],  (fp)[5],
            (fp)[6],  (fp)[7],  (fp)[8],  (fp)[9],  (fp)[10], (fp)[11],
            (fp)[12], (fp)[13], (fp)[14], (fp)[15], (fp)[16], (fp)[17],
            (fp)[18], (fp)[19],
            // overflow
            (fp)[20], (fp)[21], (fp)[22], (fp)[23], (fp)[24], (fp)[25],
            (fp)[-1], (fp)[-2], (fp)[-3], (fp)[-4], (fp)[-5], (fp)[-6]
          );

    ret = sscanf("aabb", "%2hhx%2hhx", &fp[0], &fp[1]);
    printk("ret = %d fp = %2.2hhx%2.2hhx\n", ret, fp[0], fp[1]);

    ret = sscanf(
            "ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff", 
            "%2hhx%2hhx%2hhx%2hhx%2hhx%2hhx"
            "%2hhx%2hhx%2hhx%2hhx%2hhx%2hhx"
            "%2hhx%2hhx%2hhx%2hhx%2hhx%2hhx"
            "%2hhx%2hhx",
            &(fp)[0],  &(fp)[1],  &(fp)[2],  &(fp)[3],  &(fp)[4],  &(fp)[5],
            &(fp)[6],  &(fp)[7],  &(fp)[8],  &(fp)[9],  &(fp)[10], &(fp)[11],
            &(fp)[12], &(fp)[13], &(fp)[14], &(fp)[15], &(fp)[16], &(fp)[17],
            &(fp)[18], &(fp)[19]
            );

    printk("ret = %d fp = "
            "%2.2hhx%2.2hhx%2.2hhx%2.2hhx%2.2hhx%2.2hhx"
            "%2.2hhx%2.2hhx%2.2hhx%2.2hhx%2.2hhx%2.2hhx"
            "%2.2hhx%2.2hhx%2.2hhx%2.2hhx%2.2hhx%2.2hhx"
            "%2.2hhx%2.2hhx, "
            // overflow prints (hacky)
            "after fp = "
            "%2.2hhx%2.2hhx%2.2hhx%2.2hhx%2.2hhx%2.2hhx, "
            "before fp = "
            "%2.2hhx%2.2hhx%2.2hhx%2.2hhx%2.2hhx%2.2hhx"
            "\n",
            ret,
            (fp)[0],  (fp)[1],  (fp)[2],  (fp)[3],  (fp)[4],  (fp)[5],
            (fp)[6],  (fp)[7],  (fp)[8],  (fp)[9],  (fp)[10], (fp)[11],
            (fp)[12], (fp)[13], (fp)[14], (fp)[15], (fp)[16], (fp)[17],
            (fp)[18], (fp)[19],
            (fp)[20], (fp)[21], (fp)[22], (fp)[23], (fp)[24], (fp)[25],
            (fp)[-1], (fp)[-2], (fp)[-3], (fp)[-4], (fp)[-5], (fp)[-6]
          );
}

#ifndef __KERNEL__

int main(void){
    test();
    return 0;
}

#else

static int __init test_init(void) {
    test();
    return 0;
}

static void __exit test_exit(void) {
}

module_init(test_init);
module_exit(test_exit);

#endif
```

yields:

```
=== user space ===
init, ret = 0 fp = aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa, after fp = 65005f5f7664, before fp = 000000000000
ret = 2 fp = aabb
ret = 20 fp = ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff, after fp = 65005f5f7664, before fp = 000000000000
=== kernel space ===
[386177.161037] init, ret = 0 fp = aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa, after fp = baae0dbc0000, before fp = bc0daebaffff
[386177.161044] ret = 2 fp = aabb
[386177.161061] ret = 20 fp = 000000000000000000000000ffffffffffffffff, after fp = baae0dbc0000, before fp = bc0daebaffff
```

The [test.c](https://gist.github.com/Enteee/7ceec987924d3446c384a449a085ee8d) basically reads `ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff` to `fp` using `sscanf` with a sequence of `%2hhx` format specifiers. After that, it prints `fp` using `printf` / `printk` with a sequence of `%2.2hhx` format specifiers.

Can somebody explain me why `fp` is no the same when read with [glibc sscanf](https://github.molgen.mpg.de/git-mirror/glibc/blob/20003c49884422da7ffbc459cdeee768a6fee07b/stdio-common/scanf.c) and [linux sscanf](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/lib/vsprintf.c#L2596). In addition, why is the `aabb`-test working just fine?

I already checked the [linux sscanf](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/lib/vsprintf.c#L2596) impelmentation and from what I can see it should be similar to the [glibc sscanf](https://github.molgen.mpg.de/git-mirror/glibc/blob/20003c49884422da7ffbc459cdeee768a6fee07b/stdio-common/scanf.c).

I do think I'm missing the obvious here..

---

Notes:

- the gist containing the Makefile can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/Enteee/7ceec987924d3446c384a449a085ee8d)
- this is just an example, please don't tell me that this is an ugly implementation. There are even 24 invalid reads! thx, I'm aware of that.

Comment: Please include the code in the question — not just via a gist in Github.

Comment: Based on a cursory look at the code: the kernel has an odd way of scanning strings. It converts as much of the string as it can, ignoring field width, even if the result overflows, then looks at the field width and backs up the string pointer the appropriate number of chars, while dividing the result by the base (here, 16) each time the pointer is backed up. So I suspect those backups and divisions are whittling away the first few results to 0, until the string to be parsed is small enough not to overflow.

Comment: Workaround: don't give the kernel sscanf a string of digits that will overflow a 64-bit number.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I suppose what the kernel's vsscanf implementation really needs is some maximum-field-width-aware integer parsing functions!

Comment: @IanAbbott, `vscanf()` in the kernel is just small and nice for tasks we have. Otherwise most of the code which might operate with big numbers usually parses the input using `kstrto*()` or alike.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick thank you. I was expecting that this was because of an overflow of some kind. [I do already have a working implementation](https://github.com/Enteee/xt_sslpin/blob/7fe9c06bb9530d1f0e3a3d01c2053dbd5f2092/xt_cert_finger_print.h#L206), but as I switcht to a more generic version I noticed this issue.

Comment: @IanAbbott this might be right, but I do think a `vscanf` implementation [supporting fmts with maximum field width option](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/lib/vsprintf.c#L2649) should not behave like this. But that's just my humble opinion..